# Serve Static PNG files with an "image/png" content type, not "image/x-png"

Tags: google-app-engine, png, mime-types

I'm using google app engine with Python and have a couple static .png image files but they are all being served with an "image/x-png" content-type. This is a problem when I use a browser like chrome and try to view these images as the content-type is unrecognized, which forces chrome to download it as binary, rather than displaying the image.

How can I make App Engine serve these with the proper "image/png" mime type?

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you are using Java, this is specified normally in the `mime-mapping` section in the `web.xml` file. See eg [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Changing_the_MIME_Type_for_Static_Files) or [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1017395).

In your case, I'd try

```
 <mime-mapping>
        <extension>png</extension>
        <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
 </mime-mapping>
```

In Python, it seems you should add some [handler](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles) to your `app.yaml` with the appropiate `mime_type`, for example (replace with your own `url` and `static_dir`) :

```
handlers:
- url: /static/*.png
  static_dir: static
  mime_type: image/png
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified it's for python. I found this page earlier in my search, but couldn't find the equivalent for the python app.yaml file.

Comment: For some reason, I ALSO needed to install PIL on the deploying box.  Until I did, it continued to serve as x-png...

Comment: This solution does not work if you are serving multiple file types from the same static directory.  Is there a way to match file extensions with mime types?